# how to write a ruby module to allow methods in class definition

Tags: ruby

Having a hard time figuring this out. Suppose I wanted to write a module, and when included, it would allow classes to define methods by calling a method with symbols

```
class Anything
  include Foo

  initializers :hello, :goodbye
end

module Foo

  # What goes in here? Its not 
  # def self.initializers(*symbols)

end
```

Same syntax idea as `attr_accessible`. Tried finding it in the Rails source, but, well..

Comment: Your code above will raise an error because `Foo` is included before its definition. And, what is your question?

Comment: yea it will. meant to be different files, and more part of the question than actual working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Foo

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def initializers *names
      names.each do |name|
        define_method name do
          'ok'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

class Anything
  include Foo

  initializers :hello, :goodbye
end

puts Anything.new.hello #=> ok
```

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
module Foo

  def self.included(base) 
    block = Proc.new  do |*symbols|
      puts symbols.inspect
    end
    base.class.send(:define_method, :initializers, block)  
  end

end

class Anything
  include Foo

  initializers :one, :two , :three

end
```